# Trying to read a XML file from S3 using S3 boto3 and extract data using minidom

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While trying to read the XML file from S3 and extract the data using minidom and when trying to print the tag it gives a `[]`.

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Reading the source file from  S3
    bucketName = os.environ['bucketname']
    inputfile = s3_client.Object(bucketName, os.environ['bucket_filepath']).get()['Body'].read()
    print(inputfile)
# Reading the XML File
    mytree = minidom.parseString(inputfile)
    print(mytree)
    # print(mytree.nodeName)

    # Get a list of XML tags from the document and print each one
    NotificationEventName = mytree.getElementsByTagName('NotificationEventName')[0]
    print(NotificationEventName)
```

How do we get the tag using Minidom?

Comment: Does your `print(inputfile)` line show the expected information (presumably an HTML file)? If you examine the output of `print(mytree)`, does it contain an element with the given Tag?